# Is it good to keep food in an opened can possibly in a refrigerator?

Tags: food-preservation, canning

I often cannot eat all food in a can of ready-to-eat vegetable, cranberry/tomato/spaghetti sauce, or salmon.

I keep the rest in the original can in either the refrigerator or the freezer.

I recently saw on a can of orange juice that "Refrigerate after opening in a separate container". But I haven't found similar words on other cans.

Is it safe to keep food in an opened can in general?

Does my question depend on specific food?

[image]

Comment: It this a a metal can ? maybe it a safety issue against cuts ?

Comment: Metal cans. perhaps tin cans